# Getting jointly normal variables from the vector of jointly standard normal random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

2. Let Z be the (2×1) vector of jointly standard normal random variables.

(a) From Z get a jointly normal random variables X1 and X2 such that the means and variances of X1 and X2 are given as µ1 = 0.5, µ2 = 1 σ2 1 = 1, and σ2 2 = 0.5, and the covariance is given as σ12 = 0.5.

I don't see where this problem is heading. What should this mean? Maybe should I make the pdf of the standard normal random variables and then use the transformation technique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start with: $X=\left(\begin{array}{c}
X_{1}\\
X_{2}
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
Z_{1}\\
Z_{2}
\end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{c}
\mu_{1}\\
\mu_{2}
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
aZ_{1}+bZ_{2}+\mu_{1}\\
cZ_{1}+dZ_{2}+\mu_{2}
\end{array}\right)$ where $a,b,c,d$ are constants.

Then it is assured that $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ have a joint normal
distribution with $\mathbb{E}X_{i}=\mu_{i}$ for $i=1,2$.

If $A$ denotes matrix $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{array}\right)$ then the covariance matrix of $X$ is $AA^{T}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\sigma_{X_{1}}^{2} & \mathsf{Cov}\left(X_{1},X_{2}\right)\\
\mathsf{Cov}\left(X_{1},X_{2}\right) & \sigma_{X_{2}}^{2}
\end{array}\right)$.

This provides conditions on $a,b,c,d$ and actually you are asked to find a tuple $(a,b,c,d)$ that satisfies these conditions.

Comment: One thing though, I don't get what does jointly standard normal random variable mean. Is it like the joint distribution of two standard normal distributions?

Comment: $Z_1,Z_2$ both have standard normal distribution **and** are independent. The covariance matrix of $(Z_1,Z_2)^T$ has $1$ on diagonal and $0$ on other places.